# Add accessor method without template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I have a struct made of templated types that work with incomplete types unless instantiated, like `std::vector`. Access into those types work with typesafe index wrappers. Example:

```
template<class T>
struct Idx{unsinged val;};

struct Holder{
MyVector<Foo> foos;
MyVector<Bar> bars;
};

const Foo& foo = holder.foos.get(Idx<Foo>(...));
```

This works well: `Idx` does not need to know the type of the template param because it is never used. Holder works with forward declarations of Foo/Bar too. I cannot confuse `Idx<Foo>` with `Idx<Bar>` because I can only get the respective type with them. Because this is so unique I though of adding convenience functions to holder:

```
struct Holder{
MyVector<Foo> foos;
MyVector<Bar> bars;
const Foo& get(Idx<Foo> idx) { return foos.get(idx);}
const Bar& get(Idx<Bar> idx) { return bars.get(idx);}
};
```

But now I need full types for Holder, which I wanted to avoid. Is it possible to use incomplete types AND the convenience functions? Maybe some templates help but I'd need some dispatch to either foos or bars which most likely instantiates it.

Comment: I call [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I think your requirements are a result of other bad design decisions. It's strange to have the "typesafe index wrapper" `Holder` be responsible for multiple collection types at once, instead of designing the typesafe index wrapper as a focused functionality for one generic vector/index and then using it multiple times.

Comment: Let me clearify: The index wrapper is called `Idx` which can get instances from a collection `MyVector` in a typesafe manner. `Holder` is a collection of `MyVector` of different types. `Foo` and `Bar` might be unrelated but often used together or related (`Foo` contains an `Idx<Bar>`) There is another solution: Making Foo/Bar inherit from a Base, store them as Base-Ptrs in a single container and use the type in `Idx` to static_cast them to their type. But I don't want that. I have a name for each Foo instance to get it's index and using that would require unique names for all Foo/Bar instancs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a template function

```
template<typename T>
const T& getByIndex(const MyVector<T>& vec, const Idx<T>& idx)
{ return vec.get(idx); }
```

Then you can use it inside `Holder` like

```
const Foo& get(const Idx<Foo>& idx) { return getByIndex(foos, idx); }
```

Do not expect the parameter as instance `Idx<Foo>` because this would require the fully defined type (the reference allows incomplete types).

Comment: Doesn't work. The get function instantiates getByIndex which instantiates MyVector -> Need complete T

Comment: @Flamefire it just clicked... you need to replace `Idx<Foo>` by `const Idx<Foo>&`, then it's just a reference type and incomplete type will be acceptable. Maybe you won't even need the extra `getByIndex` redirection.

Comment: Nope. The problem is not the incomplete `Idx<Foo>` the problem is the incomplete `Foo`. I'd need some indirection so I can have `const T& get(Idx<T> idx){ return getContainer<T>.get(idx); }

Comment: @Flamefire As far as I can tell, you try to keep Foo/Bar undefined within the scope of the `Helper` implementation without any rational justification. `Helper` is not generic, so its implementation *should* know the actual class definition behind `Foo` and `Bar`.

Comment: Not really. Holder is just a container of Foos and Bars. It is pretty generic. Rationale for incomplete types: Holder is accessible by many classes. Not all of them need Foo **and** Bar or not even one of them. If Foo/Bar are complex it would needlessly increase compile times for those classes that don't need them (or one of them) at all. So if a class needs Foo, it includes Foo.h and accesses it. If not, Foo is just a simply fwd declared struct.

Comment: @Flamefire thats why I say *implementation of Holder* and not *definition of Holder* You can move the `Holder::get` implementation out of the class definition into a separate cpp compilation unit and only there you will need to reference Foo and Bar... not in the header definition of the class.

Comment: Yes that's true, didn't think you actually mean the declaration opposed to definition. And yes Holder needs full types any way for ctor/dtor. But putting the get functions also there would make them not getting inlined unless LTO is turned on. And you need each function twice: definition and declaration which is IMO to much for just a simple getter. So I prefer my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution during the discussion of then answer by @grek40 :

I need a templatized get function so the containers get function does not get instantiated in the header. Hence we have:

`template<class T> const T& get(DescIdx<T> idx) const { return getContainer<T>().get(idx); }`

Now we need a `getContainer` function which is simple: `template<class T> const MyVector<T>& getContainer() const;`

This needs to be instantiated for our containers like: `template<> inline const MyVector<Foo>& Holder::getContainer() const { return foos; }`

So all in all:

```
template<class T>
struct Idx{unsinged val;};

struct Holder{
MyVector<Foo> foos;
MyVector<Bar> bars;
template<class T> const T& get(DescIdx<T> idx) const { return getContainer<T>().get(idx); }
template<class T> const MyVector<T>& getContainer() const;
};

template<> inline const MyVector<Foo>& Holder::getContainer() const { return foos; }
template<> inline const MyVector<Bar>& Holder::getContainer() const { return bars; }

// Somewhere else
const Foo& foo = holder.get(Idx<Foo>(...));
```

This might be improved by using template metaprogramming. Steps:

1. Define a boost::mpl::list of all types (Foo, Bar)
2. Create a templatized struct `MetaHolder` that holds 1 `MyVector<T>`
3. Let Holder inherit from `MetaHolder` instantiated with each type
4. Implement 1(!) generic getContainer functions which simply returns `MetaHolder<T>.container`.

Everything will get resolved at compile time, so no runtime overhead. Not sure about compile time overhead though as Boost.MPL can get quite heavy.